# As in versus like in

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

> "B as in batman"
>
> "B like in batman"
>
> "Zero as in zero chance"
>
> "Zero like in zero chance"

I heard that like in and as in are not synonymous like used above, so I was surprised because I always used them as such, but I guess I was wrong on this. Can anyone tell me why it's wrong?

Comment: For "as in" to be compared to "like" in your examples, your example would be "B like Batman," not "B like *in* Batman," and your example would be "Zero like zero chance," not "Zero like *in* zero chance." You need to figure out what you're asking and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: As a British English speaker, I would say "B as in Batman" when spelling out a word.

Comment: As a Canadian, all three of these sound natural: "B as in Batman", "B like in Batman", "Be like Batman".

Answer (score 1):

They're quite similar, and either is probably acceptable.  "As in" is more common, because "as" implies a stronger relationship to intended function, whereas "like" implies mere similarity.  For instance—"I used the rock as a hammer" focuses more on the action of hammering something with the rock, whereas "I used the rock like a hammer" focuses more on the similarity between the rock and a hammer.  Similarly, saying "B as in Batman" highlights that of course it's *that* B, and not D or something, because clearly only B fulfills the function of the first letter in Batman—but "B like in Batman" focuses on the similarity between the letter B by itself and the letter B in Batman.  The latter, of course, is a little odd, because they're both the letter B, so they're completely identical.  But really the difference is quite small, so again—either is fine.

If, however, you are trying to specify a particular definition of a word, such as "fast as/like in 'hold fast to'", then highlighting the function or the similarity accomplishes the same purpose, so the two are essentially on equal footing there.